# debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP

Tags: ssh

I have two servers A and B. A and B can ssh into each other and other servers but cannot ssh into server C. All servers can ssh into A and B (including server C)
The request hangs up at the following:

```
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
```

and eventually times out. If I do a `netstat -a` I see an established connection on server C and server A or B. When I tail the log on server C, I see a connection attempt but I never completes. I can ping as well as traceroute in both directions.

Comment: You will find a more detailed answer here:

https://superuser.com/questions/568891/ssh-works-in-putty-but-not-terminal

Answer (score 9):

I've found same problem.

In my case:

- Client SSH version: OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5, OpenSSL 1.0.1k 8 Jan 201
- Server SSH version: OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013

It seem's there is a problem related with this ssh server version because I use same client with a lot of different remote systems without any issue.

After a lot of tests playing with MTU values I finally found that the solution was to remove hmac-md5 from the list of MAC algorithms.

In `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` edit the next line:

```
#   MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160
MACs hmac-sha1
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Upvoting for the mere fact that you mentioned MTU, which solved my problem... to be specific, my ssh session transited routed interfaces with different MTUs.  I fixed the asymmetric routing and this fixed the issue as well.

Comment: I had this bug on Debian Jessie and this fixed it.

Comment: saved my day, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

add -c aes256-ctr

solution via http://www.held.org.il/blog/2011/05/the-myterious-case-of-broken-ssh-client-connection-reset-by-peer/

I discovered this issue today trying to log into a new bitnami LAPP stack (OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.4 pat OpenSSH_5*) from the AWS Store from a Mac running 10.9.4 (OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011).

Comment: Add it to what?  Detail is always appreciated.

Comment: This works. A more root solution seems to be turning off jumbo frames on my OS X client computer also solves it without having to shorted the cypher suite.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked version of openssh-server and client.
I've found that it were downgraded and after downgrade connecting ends with this message.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/512366)