# Unable to SSH into server

Tags: ssh

I'm trying to SSH into a server and I'm receiving a `Connection closed` message every time. I've tried changing MTU settings on both server and client side without success.

Here are the server side logs:

```
-> /usr/sbin/sshd -e -p 27 -D -d -e   -o StrictModes=no -o SyslogFacility=DAEMON -o PermitRootLogin=prohibit-password 

debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_8.4, OpenSSL 1.1.1j  16 Feb 2021
debug1: private host key #0: ssh-rsa SHA256:Q76xVI+MO2LQky0e582943UWrAYfdTh0Q5hj9YpAMPY
debug1: private host key #1: ssh-dss SHA256:Lnp91+XIE3NVI4KLmk8Ara28s9qwX3+k4PY0iVYIgXY
debug1: private host key #2: ecdsa-sha2-nistp521 SHA256:QHUFHadquHxJYJ7qB4F2K+aJEoIysOJda2vY8lP5mVY
debug1: private host key #3: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:Y2YjbYM14maKA+09EvCfq+oJ5nfqQ5RAxo9xUJ6ByFM
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd'
debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-e'
debug1: rexec_argv[2]='-p'
debug1: rexec_argv[3]='27'
debug1: rexec_argv[4]='-D'
debug1: rexec_argv[5]='-d'
debug1: rexec_argv[6]='-e'
debug1: rexec_argv[7]='-o'
debug1: rexec_argv[8]='StrictModes=no'
debug1: rexec_argv[9]='-o'
debug1: rexec_argv[10]='SyslogFacility=DAEMON'
debug1: rexec_argv[11]='-o'
debug1: rexec_argv[12]='PermitRootLogin=prohibit-password'
debug1: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj from 0 to -1000
debug1: Bind to port 27 on 0.0.0.0.
Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 27.
debug1: Bind to port 27 on ::.
Server listening on :: port 27.
debug1: Server will not fork when running in debugging mode.
debug1: rexec start in 5 out 5 newsock 5 pipe -1 sock 8
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_8.4, OpenSSL 1.1.1j  16 Feb 2021
debug1: private host key #0: ssh-rsa SHA256:Q76xVI+MO2LQky0e582943UWrAYfdTh0Q5hj9YpAMPY
debug1: private host key #1: ssh-dss SHA256:Lnp91+XIE3NVI4KLmk8Ara28s9qwX3+k4PY0iVYIgXY
debug1: private host key #2: ecdsa-sha2-nistp521 SHA256:QHUFHadquHxJYJ7qB4F2K+aJEoIysOJda2vY8lP5mVY
debug1: private host key #3: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:Y2YjbYM14maKA+09EvCfq+oJ5nfqQ5RAxo9xUJ6ByFM
debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3
Connection from 192.168.1.172 port 54044 on 192.168.1.227 port 27
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.5
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.5 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 1001/1001 [preauth]
debug1: list_hostkey_types: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256 [preauth]
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT [preauth]
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks [preauth]
debug1: monitor_read_log: child log fd closed
debug1: do_cleanup
debug1: Killing privsep child 404
255
iex(48)> Toolshed.cmd("/usr/sbin/sshd -e -p 27 -D -d -e   -o StrictModes=no -o SyslogFacility=DAEMON -o PermitRootLogin=prohibit-password")
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_8.4, OpenSSL 1.1.1j  16 Feb 2021
debug1: private host key #0: ssh-rsa SHA256:Q76xVI+MO2LQky0e582943UWrAYfdTh0Q5hj9YpAMPY
debug1: private host key #1: ssh-dss SHA256:Lnp91+XIE3NVI4KLmk8Ara28s9qwX3+k4PY0iVYIgXY
debug1: private host key #2: ecdsa-sha2-nistp521 SHA256:QHUFHadquHxJYJ7qB4F2K+aJEoIysOJda2vY8lP5mVY
debug1: private host key #3: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:Y2YjbYM14maKA+09EvCfq+oJ5nfqQ5RAxo9xUJ6ByFM
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd'
debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-e'
debug1: rexec_argv[2]='-p'
debug1: rexec_argv[3]='27'
debug1: rexec_argv[4]='-D'
debug1: rexec_argv[5]='-d'
debug1: rexec_argv[6]='-e'
debug1: rexec_argv[7]='-o'
debug1: rexec_argv[8]='StrictModes=no'
debug1: rexec_argv[9]='-o'
debug1: rexec_argv[10]='SyslogFacility=DAEMON'
debug1: rexec_argv[11]='-o'
debug1: rexec_argv[12]='PermitRootLogin=prohibit-password'
debug1: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj from 0 to -1000
debug1: Bind to port 27 on 0.0.0.0.
Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 27.
debug1: Bind to port 27 on ::.
Server listening on :: port 27.
debug1: Server will not fork when running in debugging mode.
debug1: rexec start in 5 out 5 newsock 5 pipe -1 sock 8
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_8.4, OpenSSL 1.1.1j  16 Feb 2021
debug1: private host key #0: ssh-rsa SHA256:Q76xVI+MO2LQky0e582943UWrAYfdTh0Q5hj9YpAMPY
debug1: private host key #1: ssh-dss SHA256:Lnp91+XIE3NVI4KLmk8Ara28s9qwX3+k4PY0iVYIgXY
debug1: private host key #2: ecdsa-sha2-nistp521 SHA256:QHUFHadquHxJYJ7qB4F2K+aJEoIysOJda2vY8lP5mVY
debug1: private host key #3: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:Y2YjbYM14maKA+09EvCfq+oJ5nfqQ5RAxo9xUJ6ByFM
debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3
Connection from 192.168.1.172 port 54250 on 192.168.1.227 port 27
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.5
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.5 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 1001/1001 [preauth]
debug1: list_hostkey_types: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256 [preauth]
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT [preauth]
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks [preauth]
debug1: monitor_read_log: child log fd closed
debug1: do_cleanup
debug1: Killing privsep child 409
```

Here are the client side logs:

```
✗ ssh -p 27   root@192.168.1.227 -v

OpenSSH_8.5p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/eric/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.227 [192.168.1.227] port 27.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/eric/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/eric/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/eric/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/eric/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/eric/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/eric/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/eric/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/eric/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/eric/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 3
debug1: identity file /home/eric/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/eric/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/eric/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/eric/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/eric/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.5
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.4
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_8.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.1.227:27 as 'root'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
Connection closed by 192.168.1.227 port 27
```

Any additional flags that would help in debugging? I've verified that I'm able to ssh to other servers.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your main issue can like be identified by the line where it says `expecting SSH2_MSG_KEY_ECDH_REPLY`. A similar issue happened to someone a while ago from the post found [here](https://serverfault.com/a/670081/623763).

The accepted solution by @shgnInc was to perform one of the following commands:

```
sudo ip li set mtu 1200 dev wlan0
```

or

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 mtu 1200
```

An alternative solution if those didn't work can be found in the next answer [here](https://serverfault.com/a/676026/623763) or to try any of the later ones to see if they work for you

Comment: I tried changing the mtu settings based on that thread and haven't been able to make that work. I've tried changing the MAC, KeyAlgorithms, and Ciphers as well without any luck.